# Failed to construct 'CustomElement': The result must not have a parent

Tags: javascript, es6-class, custom-element

I am creating Custom HTML Element using [Web Components](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_custom_elements)

I retrieve some JSON data via a REST Service and want to create Custom Elements dynamically based on the response.

```
class LibraryFolders extends HTMLElement {
    async connectedCallback() {
        // Load folders
        const foldersResponse = await fetch('/wp-json/prodes-media-library/v1/folders');
        const foldersResponseJson = await foldersResponse.json();

        foldersResponseJson.forEach(folder => {
            document.createElement('library-folder');
        });
    }
}

customElements.define('library-folders', LibraryFolders);
```

This works correctly, when creating the element using `createElement` it calls the `constructor` in the customElement class called `LibraryFolder`

```
class LibraryFolder extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
        super();

        // logs <library-folder></library-folder>
        console.log(this);

        // This results eventually into the following error:
        // Failed to construct 'CustomElement': The result must not have a parent
        document.querySelector('#folders').appendChild(this);
    }
}

customElements.define('library-folder', LibraryFolder);
```

What I try to archieve is to *append* the `library-folder` element to an element called `<div id="folders"></div>` as soon the `constructor` in  `class LibraryFolder` is fired.

However, when trying that this results into the following error:

> **Uncaught DOMException: Failed to construct 'CustomElement': The result must not have a parent**
>           at HTMLDocument.createElement (:1:1536)
>           at HTMLDocument.document.createElement (:292:44)
>           at (URL)
>           at Array.forEach ()
>           at HTMLElement.connectedCallback (URL)

What am I doing wrong here? There is no information about this error in the documentation, unlike other similar errors.

Comment: Perhaps it's telling you that the component needs to be added to the DOM *after* it's created. That exception is coming from inside `createElement`, indicating that it checks the object created by your constructor to verify that it's not already part of the DOM, which should not be the case for the return value from `createElement` if you think about it.

Comment: @Pointy So I should not add it to the DOM inside the constructor?

Comment: Right. Think about it: the concept of `createElement()` in normal circumstances is to make a new element that can later be added to the DOM somewhere, or not. An element that adds itself to the DOM would be weird. (For one thing, it wouldn't work independently of a particular page structure.)

Comment: @Pointy Yes, `An element that adds itself to the DOM would be weird` that sounds logic. Let me try that and come back to you to see if it worked.

Comment: @Pointy Thanks you, I you have send me into the right direction and I managed to solve it using your comments. Ive added it as answer for future people having the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [@pointy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/182668/pointy) to send me into the right direction.

> An element that adds itself to the DOM would be weird. (For one thing,
>   it wouldn't work independently of a particular page structure.)

---

The problem was that I was trying to add the *element* using its own `constructor` to the *DOM*, I also figured out that if you managed to get it working inside the `constructor` that it will result into.

> Maximum call stack size exceeded.

I managed to fix the issue by creating a function inside the class which can be called later on to append the *element* to the *DOM*.

```
class LibraryFolder extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }

    appendToDom() {
        // Moved this outside the constructor
        document.querySelector('#folders').appendChild(this);;
    }
}

customElements.define('library-folder', LibraryFolder);
```

And then in the `LibraryFolders` class call that function.

```
class LibraryFolders extends HTMLElement {
    async connectedCallback() {
        // Load folders
        const foldersResponse = await fetch('/wp-json/prodes-media-library/v1/folders');
        const foldersResponseJson = await foldersResponse.json();

        foldersResponseJson.forEach(folder => {
            const node = document.createElement('library-folder');

            // Now it works correctly :)
            node.appendToDom();
        });
    }
}

customElements.define('library-folders', LibraryFolders);
```

Just to add, this error is correct according to specs.
`If result’s parent is not null, then throw a "NotSupportedError" DOMException.`

Chrome doesn't give the correct error, but if you try it in Firefox you will get the specified error

For more details check out
https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-document-createelement

Comment: Haven't tried it but shouldn't ``this.append(...folderResponseJson.map(f=>document.createElement('library-folder'))`` be better for performance and decoupling